# Comparing a distribution law with its density function in R

Tags: r, distributions, density-function, t-distribution

I want to generate a sample of a student t distribution with a certain length and a certain degree of freedom and compare it in the same graphic with its density funcion. How could i aproach that?

- I've been trying with the function `repeat()` and `sample()` for the
  length of the sample but it would not work out.
- What, i guess,  is left is puting the vector i get in a variable and loading the
  histogram on the screen use a function to get the next graphic in the
  same window and compare it like this, but, how could i compare it  coherently with the density function?

Comment: See `?rt`, `?rd`, `?hist` and `?density` for documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **R** you can do:

```
df <- 2
samples <- rt(100, df)
x_seq <- seq(min(samples), max(samples), length.out = 100)
plot(x_seq, dt(x_seq, df), type = "l")
lines(density(samples), col = 2)
```

Which gives you something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why the ´x_seq´ variable?

Comment: The density functions needs to be evaluated on a finite number of positions. x_seq is this finite grid that ranges from `min(samples)` to `max(samples)` in 100 steps. So `dt(x_seq, df)` is $f(x_t)$ - the density - at the position's $t$ of x_seq